# What to use instead of dontReplace for constructing a data URI?

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, uri, data-uri

The obsolete `Uri(string, bool)` constructor is used to construct a URI from an already escaped string (obsolete presumably not to break the program if an invalid string is presented). However, I find myself in a situation where I need to pass literal bytes via the URI, and I can't think of a better way to encode them.

I am constructing a `data:` URI, which is a standardized way to pass the whole resource instead of its identifier. Although I am aware it has a `;base64` specifier to mark the passed data as encoded in base64, there are situations when the URI is shorter without base64, for example when there are less binary data. Because I don't want to worry about encodings, I simply want to pass the bytes together with the URI as an URI-encoded string, using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(byte[])`.

Since I am practically left with no other choice than to let .NET encode the string for me, without having to use obsolete constructors, and there is no `Uri(byte[])` constructor (there should be, in my opinion), what are my options to construct the URI?

I thought about using `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)` to create a string from the bytes and use that, as cp1252 can decode any character, but it seems the internal *Uri* encoding method uses UTF-8 to encode the characters, so I don't find it possible to use a text encoding at all.

What are my options? Is it okay to continue using the obsolete constructor, if there is no other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the standard *Uri* constructor accepts pre-encoded URIs, and doesn't replace valid `%` characters, so using the *dontReplace* parameter isn't really necessary when constructing *Uri* from a valid URI string containing encoded parts. They won't get re-encoded.

Answer (score 0):

> there are situations when the URI is shorter without base64, for example when there are less binary data

The URI is shorter without base64 every time, because base64 produces text from a deliberately limited character repertoire from octets.

The time base64 can be not used is when the data is textual. Otherwise the result is going to be gibberish.

> as cp1252 can decode any character

No, it can encode only 251 characters unlike say UTF-8 which can encode every character in the UCS. UTF-8 cannot decode every sequence of bytes, while some incorrect CP-1252 implementations fill the gaps (e.g. 0x81) in CP-1252 with something, but even if you could depend on that (you can't) this isn't sensible because you are building a string so the matter of encoding doesn't matter yet, except for any %-escaped characters, and they will always be escaped according to their encoding in UTF-8. (A long time ago URLs [the term *URI* didn't exist yet] could be escaped according to other encodings, but that didn't work because there was no way to know what encoding had been used, hence the standards mandating UTF-8 since 1998).

> Is it okay to continue using the obsolete constructor

No, it produces buggy results.

URIs are built on top of text. If your data is textual then just encode it by normal URI rules through `Uri.EscapeDataString()`. If your data is not textual then use base-64 to encode it as text, and then go from there. Don't try to put something in a URI that isn't meaningful in a URI.

Comment: data URI was defined in 1998 RFC, and according to the specification, a charset may be specified to correctly interpret the data. For this reason, `data:text/plain;charset=windows-1250,%A9` displays the © symbol, but `data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,%A9` doesn't. The data is interpreted based on the type and charset, and not on UTF-8 universally. The data may not be entirely textual, just mostly text with some binary data in between, which would still make base64 inefficient.

Comment: Yes, in fact it came out on the same day as the RFC that made UTF-8 the basis for how escaping works in URIs.